# Refreshing listview items after deleting one item

Tags: android, listview

This problem has encountered to me and lots of bodies here but yet i haven't seen an efficient answer.
i have a listview and a delete button for each item of the list. when i click on the button, the item is deleted from the database and also removed from the list but the listview doesn't refresh the items.

i have called the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` but has no result.(when the item is deleted the title of the next item comes up and it seems there is two item with one title, sorted one after another one).
`myListView.invalidateViews()` and `myListView.invalidate()` didn't work too.

whats the exact reason and whats the absolute solution?

Here is my code:

here are the whole codes:

public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> notes) {
    super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_note, notes);
}

private class ViewHolder {

    TextView     txtTitle;
    ImageView    imgDelete;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        imgDelete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
    }

    public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<StructNote> adapter, final StructNote item, final int position) {
        txtTitle.setText(item.title + "");          
        imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                G.notes.remove(item);
                adapter.remove(item);
                deleteDataFromDatabase(item.id);
                G.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    StructNote item = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_note, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.fill(this, item, position);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: What is that `fill()` function? When is it called? By who? And with which parameters?

Comment: Show more snippet if possible

Comment: what is "item" here and what is "deleteItem"?

Comment: i wrote the whole codes above. please check the codes. this problem is really annoying me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the item from the list or ArrayList belongs to the adapter according to the index of the list and then try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing concerning the 'two items with same title part' has to do with loss of synchronization between the listener and the current position. Try something like this, if your custom item is of type:

```
Object item
```

Put it in the view-holder alongside your text-views. After inflating the view, do this:

```
holder.item = getItem(position);
```

And then, instead of item.xx do it:

```
holder.item.xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple thing that you need to remove it from the adapter by calling `yourAdapterObject.remove(POSITION);`

Here, `yourAdapterObject` is the object of the adapter and `POSITION` is the position you want to remove from listview.

After that you need to refresh the adapter with the remaining data and information. So for that you need to call as below:

```
yourAdapterObject.notifyDataStateChanged();
```

In Addition [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) is the Animation demo given by the developer site for showing animation. But they also shows, how to remove item from list and add it into list. All works fine with nice animation effect.

I guess it will surly help you.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: i did it but didn't work.
assume, i have 3 items in my list with titles: text1, text2 and text3; and also a delete button besides each item. when i click on the delete button next to text2, the item text2 is deleted but the list show me 3 item:text1,text3 and text3! (in fact text2 is deleted but what the list shows is this: the below item comes up)
when i exit the program and run it again there is no text2 at all.
i don't want to restart the app. i want my list getting refreshed when i click on the delete button.

Comment: there is something you are missing to update or refresh for sure. Can you please put your java file from where you are using this functionality so that i can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from your array-list and set adapter to your list view again. do this in **OnItemClickListener**.

```
private OnItemClickListener listPairedClickItem = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        arrlist.remove(2);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int pos = nameList.indexOf(object);
nameList.remove(pos);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the discussion...

When I did it from a class where I use the adapter, the listview just won't refreshed. Even worse, at one point, sometimes it's refreshed, sometimes it's not. And I have called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Finally I got it work by making a method to delete item directly inside the adapter, like this:

```
CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public void deleteItem(AdapterItem ai) {
        dataList.remove(ai); /*dataList = data source used by adapter*/
        notifyDataSetChanged();   
    }
}
```